# Why is the window painted strangely (without visual styles) after sending WM_NCDESTROY?

Tags: c, winapi

I get strange window painting after I send `WM_NCDESTROY` manually. This only happens when visual styles are on. When 'Classic style' is on it does not seem to affect the window. I do not pass `WM_NCDESTROY` to `DefWindowProc()` when I send it manually, but the window still gets painted strangely. It seems like `SendMessage()` is processing `WM_NCDESTROY`. Why is `WM_NCDESTROY` getting processed even though I do not pass it to `DefWindowProc()`?

```
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE g_hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static BOOL bProcessMsg = FALSE;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCDESTROY, 0, 0);
        //Size window manually after this message is processed to see the effects
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        bProcessMsg = TRUE;
        break;

    case WM_NCDESTROY: 
        if(!bProcessMsg) return 0;
        MessageBox(0, L"Message processed", 0, MB_OK);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;

    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc1(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_MBUTTONUP:
        {
            WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
            wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
            wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
            wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
            wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
            wc.hInstance     = g_hInst;
            wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc2;
            wc.lpszClassName = L"Testclass2";
            if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0;
            CreateWindowEx(0, L"Testclass2", L"Test2", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 40, 40, 200, 200, hwnd, 0, g_hInst, 0);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc1;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Testclass";
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0;

    g_hInst = hInstance;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Testclass", L"Test1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if(!hwnd) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Before right clicking on Test2

[image]

After right clicking on Test2

[image]

Comment: Umm.. and why exactly are you sending `WM_NCDESTROY` yourself?

Comment: For testing purposes. It seems like any process can send you this message and there's no way to protect against it since `SendMessage()` is handling it itself

Comment: None of this makes any sense. If another process decides to send a `WM_NCDESTROY` message to a window in your process, so be it. It's nothing you can protect yourself against. Just implement your application to work for the normal case (i.e. on systems that don't have rogue applications running, thrashing other programs).

Comment: Yes, some messages are handled specially, no you can't protect against malicious programs sending you messages (like WM_TIMER for arbitrary code execution) except with UIPI, and why are you on Windows XP?

Comment: WM_NCDESTROY is rather special, it is guaranteed to be the *last* message that a window ever receives before it is destroyed.  It gets lots and lots of use because of that, you always use it when you *subclass* a window.  Like the Visual Styles renderer will do to make a window look different and stop making it look different because it isn't around anymore.  Well, oops there.

Comment: You have to love these questions. *When I do something absolutely wrong, that I'm never supposed to do, it causes me problems. Why?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WM_NCDESTROY message is rather special, it is guaranteed to be the **last** message that a window ever receives before it is destroyed.  It is generated by the DestroyWindow() function.

Being last gives it a rather exalted status.  It signals "stop doing what you've been doing".  For example, you always use it when you *subclass* a window; this message tells you to stop subclassing it.  And you'd always use it in a C++ wrapper class for a window, where it tells you when the C++ object needs to be destroyed.  And it is pretty likely to be the notification that the Visual Styles renderer uses to stop making a window look different because it isn't around anymore.

Oops.

Messages like that are *notifications* that something interesting happened.  As opposed to the kind of messages that are intended to *make* something interesting happen, like WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_COMMAND.  Most obvious in the WM_CLOSE vs WM_DESTROY message.  WM_CLOSE is "please close the window". You can monkey with that and refuse to close the window, traditionally with the "Data not saved, are you sure" message.  WM_DESTROY is "it is closed".  That's a rock, it really did get destroyed, no point in ever monkeying with that one.

If you generate a fake notification, then you should be prepared to get a fake outcome.  Don't mess with the important ones.